# Using telprompt in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, telprompt

I decided use telprompt to make a phone call from my app. The problem is that I need to cancel some code when user press Cancel button that appears when telprompt is called. How can detect user press Cancel button? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CTCallCenter and CTCall to monitor the call state.

With CTCallCenter you can monitor when a call is dialing, connected, or disconnected.

If the phone doesn't start dialing and your app becomes active again, the user pressed Cancel.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your answer. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Eric, I use CTCallCenter to check if call is dialling (CTCallStateDialing). But only if call is connected (CTCallStateConnected), I'm getting into the block where I print a log. Am I doing something wrong?